# Is there any benefits to connecting a PC to 4G router via Ethernet cable?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a PC connected to 4G router via Ethernet cable, is there any benefits versus WiFi connection coming from same 4G router in terms of latency, packet-loss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure speed (bandwidth) it doesn't make much difference as the data-speed over 4G will be the limiting factor in most cases.

But:

1. Wired ethernet has somewhat better latency than wireless ethernet (Wifi).
2. Wired ethernet is not subject to signal interference/jamming by other Wifi, babyphones, cordless phones, micro-waves and tons of other devices using the same radio wavelenghts as Wifi.
3. Signal dropout over Wifi (see point 2) often necessitates re-connects of the PC to the Wifi Access-point. Every (re-)connect to Wifi takes some handshake packets to be send back and forth that make point 2 even worse as they add to the reconnect time. Drops are very rare on wired connections. If you get them you need to find an UTP cable that isn't broken.
4. Wifi speed/bandwidth decreases as you get further away from the access-point and eventually becomes to weak to be useful. 20-50 meters is usually the maximum distance depending on walls, furniture and general humidity in the area. Wired the distance makes no difference, unless you exceed the 100 meter maximum cable-length. (In case you are wondering about humidity: The 2.4 GHz frequency is somewhat subject to being easily absorbed by water. In humid conditions the air and walls are more saturated with moisture and dampen the signal more.)